# Problem installing package mysqlclient on shared hosting

Tags: django, cpanel, python-3.7

I would like to install this package to contact the hosting database
but

I have a problem installing the package mysqlclient on shared hosting 
Where these orders were used

```
 pip install mysqlclient
easy_install mysqlclient
```

Where this error resulted

```
        pip install mysqlclient
    Collecting mysqlclient
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
    Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /home2/ali/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8e2vv1i/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-wtifemuw --python-tag cp37:
    ERROR: /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -g -fstack-protector -m64 -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
    Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
    Failed to build mysqlclient
    Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /home2/ali/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8e2vv1i/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ifk1qcfb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home2/bekolear/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:
    ERROR: /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -g -fstack-protector -m64 -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command "/home2/ali/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8e2vv1i/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ifk1qcfb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home2/ali/virtualenv/myproject/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-j8e2vv1i/mysqlclient/
```

I can not use some commands like sudo
Or all root commands

Help me install this package and contact the database

Comment: From tag [tag:python-3.7] I think that you have to use `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I have same problem. I have a shared hosting where I run Django. With SQLite it works fine but when I try to switch my database to mysql using mysqlclient, the package doesn't install. I'm searching for idea that I can compile locally and upload to server and use. Is that possible.